# Aligning Lists of Matching Elements

Tags: python

I have 4 lists:

```
sorted_six_HUP=     ['CB THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', 'CB PHE 65 A', 'CZ ARG 67 A', 'NE ARG 67 A', 'NH2 ARG 67 A', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B', 'CB PHE 200 B', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', 'CB TYR 205 B', 'CD1 TYR 205 B', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', 'CE1 TYR 205 B', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B', 'CZ TYR 205 B', 'OH TYR 205 B', 'CE1 TYR 97 B', 'OH TYR 97 B', 'CB THR 130 D', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', 'CB PHE 65 D', 'CD1 PHE 65 D', 'CE1 PHE 65 D', 'CZ ARG 67 D', 'NE ARG 67 D', 'NH2 ARG 67 D', 'CD GLU 155 E', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E', 'C TYR 157 E', 'CA TYR 157 E', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', 'CZ TYR 157 E', 'O TYR 157 E', 'OH TYR 157 E', 'CB THR 202 E', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', 'CB TYR 205 E', 'CD1 TYR 205 E', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', 'CE1 TYR 205 E', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', 'CG TYR 205 E', 'CZ TYR 205 E', 'OH TYR 97 E']
GABA_sorted_six_HUP= ['CG2 ILE 228 A', 'O ILE 228 A', 'CB LEU 232 A', 'CD1 LEU 232 A', 'CA PRO 233 A', 'CB PRO 233 A', 'CG PRO 233 A', 'O PRO 233 A', 'SD MET 236 A', 'OG1 THR 237 A', 'C MET 261 B', 'CA MET 261 B', 'CB MET 261 B', 'CE MET 261 B', 'O MET 261 B', 'CG2 THR 262 B', 'OG1 THR 262 B', 'CG ASN 265 B', 'ND2 ASN 265 B', 'C LEU 285 B', 'CB LEU 285 B', 'O LEU 285 B', 'CE MET 286 B', 'CG MET 286 B', 'N MET 286 B', 'SD MET 286 B', 'CB PHE 289 B', 'CD1 PHE 289 B', 'CD2 PHE 289 B', 'CE1 PHE 289 B', 'CE2 PHE 289 B', 'CG PHE 289 B', 'CZ PHE 289 B', 'CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C', 'ND2 ASN 60 C', 'CE2 PHE 77 C', 'CZ PHE 77 C', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D', 'CA HIS 102 D', 'CB HIS 102 D', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D', 'O SER 159 D', 'CD1 TYR 160 D', 'CE1 TYR 160 D', 'O TYR 160 D', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D', 'CA SER 205 D', 'CB SER 205 D', 'OG SER 205 D', 'N SER 206 D', 'CB TYR 210 D', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', 'CE1 TYR 210 D', 'CG TYR 210 D', 'O ILE 228 D', 'CB LEU 232 D', 'CD1 LEU 232 D', 'CA PRO 233 D', 'CB PRO 233 D', 'CG PRO 233 D', 'SD MET 236 D', 'CD2 LEU 269 D', 'C MET 261 E', 'CA MET 261 E', 'CB MET 261 E', 'CE MET 261 E', 'O MET 261 E', 'CG2 THR 262 E', 'OG1 THR 262 E', 'CB ASN 265 E', 'CG ASN 265 E', 'ND2 ASN 265 E', 'C LEU 285 E', 'CB LEU 285 E', 'O LEU 285 E', 'CA MET 286 E', 'CG MET 286 E', 'N MET 286 E', 'CB PHE 289 E', 'CD1 PHE 289 E', 'CD2 PHE 289 E', 'CE2 PHE 289 E', 'CG PHE 289 E', 'CZ PHE 289 E']
sorted_six_HUO=      ['CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C', 'OD1 ASN 60 C', 'CE1 PHE 77 C', 'CE2 PHE 77 C', 'CZ PHE 77 C', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D', 'C HIS 102 D', 'CA HIS 102 D', 'CB HIS 102 D', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D', 'O SER 159 D', 'CA TYR 160 D', 'O TYR 160 D', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D', 'CA SER 205 D', 'CB SER 205 D', 'OG SER 205 D', 'N SER 206 D', 'CB TYR 210 D', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', 'CG TYR 210 D']
GABA_sorted_six_HUO: ['CD2 LEU 118 A', 'CB THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', 'CZ ARG 67 A', 'NE ARG 67 A', 'NH2 ARG 67 A', 'CD GLU 155 B', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B', 'CB PHE 200 B', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', 'CB THR 202 B', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B', 'CZ TYR 205 B', 'CE1 TYR 97 B', 'CZ TYR 97 B', 'OH TYR 97 B', 'CD2 LEU 118 D', 'CB THR 130 D', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', 'CD ARG 67 D', 'CZ ARG 67 D', 'NE ARG 67 D', 'NH2 ARG 67 D', 'CD GLU 155 E', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E', 'CA TYR 157 E', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', 'O TYR 157 E', 'CB PHE 200 E', 'CE2 PHE 200 E', 'CB THR 202 E', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', 'CZ TYR 205 E', 'CE1 TYR 97 E', 'CZ TYR 97 E', 'OH TYR 97 E']


big_list = [ sorted_six_HUP , GABA_sorted_six_HUP, sorted_six_HUO , GABA_sorted_six_HUO ]
```

I am trying to align all the lists so that each matching element has its match in the list right below  it, this makes analyzing the data a lot easier so I don't have to hunt and poke and spend time trying to see commonalities when instead I can lay them all out right in front of me.

So using a sorted key to make the intial sorted lists above and Pandas to make the alignment I tried this:

```
def last(str):
    return str.split()[-1]+str.split()[-2]+str.split()[0] # Returns a string that begins with the letter, followed by the number

sorted_six_HUO          = sorted(benzo_pocket_array_6HUO , key=last)
sorted_six_HUP          = sorted(benzo_pocket_array_6HUP , key=last)
GABA_sorted_six_HUO = sorted(GABA_pocket_array_6HUO, key=last)
GABA_sorted_six_HUP = sorted(GABA_pocket_array_6HUP, key=last)
```

```
big_dict = [ {k:k for k in i} for i in big_list]



df = pd.DataFrame(big_dict)
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns,key=last), axis = 1)# Sorts the columns by their headers.

df.fillna(value = "             ", inplace = True) # Replaces NaN with "
```

Which got me a partially correct answer, but it seems as the lists continues the alignment slips and skews the alignment.

```
['             ', 'CB THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CB PHE 65 A', 'CZ ARG 67 A', 'NE ARG 67 A', 'NH2 ARG 67 A', '             ', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B', 'CB PHE 200 B', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', '             ', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', 'CB TYR 205 B', 'CD1 TYR 205 B', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', 'CE1 TYR 205 B', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B', 'CZ TYR 205 B', 'OH TYR 205 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CE1 TYR 97 B', '             ', 'OH TYR 97 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CB THR 130 D', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CB PHE 65 D', 'CD1 PHE 65 D', 'CE1 PHE 65 D', '             ', 'CZ ARG 67 D', 'NE ARG 67 D', 'NH2 ARG 67 D', 'CD GLU 155 E', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E', 'C TYR 157 E', 'CA TYR 157 E', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', 'CZ TYR 157 E', 'O TYR 157 E', 'OH TYR 157 E', '             ', '             ', 'CB THR 202 E', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', 'CB TYR 205 E', 'CD1 TYR 205 E', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', 'CE1 TYR 205 E', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', 'CG TYR 205 E', 'CZ TYR 205 E', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'OH TYR 97 E']
['             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CG2 ILE 228 A', 'O ILE 228 A', 'CB LEU 232 A', 'CD1 LEU 232 A', 'CA PRO 233 A', 'CB PRO 233 A', 'CG PRO 233 A', 'O PRO 233 A', 'SD MET 236 A', 'OG1 THR 237 A', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'C MET 261 B', 'CA MET 261 B', 'CB MET 261 B', 'CE MET 261 B', 'O MET 261 B', 'CG2 THR 262 B', 'OG1 THR 262 B', 'CG ASN 265 B', 'ND2 ASN 265 B', 'C LEU 285 B', 'CB LEU 285 B', 'O LEU 285 B', 'CE MET 286 B', 'CG MET 286 B', 'N MET 286 B', 'SD MET 286 B', 'CB PHE 289 B', 'CD1 PHE 289 B', 'CD2 PHE 289 B', 'CE1 PHE 289 B', 'CE2 PHE 289 B', 'CG PHE 289 B', 'CZ PHE 289 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C', 'ND2 ASN 60 C', '             ', '             ', 'CE2 PHE 77 C', 'CZ PHE 77 C', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D', '             ', 'CA HIS 102 D', 'CB HIS 102 D', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'O SER 159 D', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 160 D', 'CE1 TYR 160 D', 'O TYR 160 D', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D', 'CA SER 205 D', 'CB SER 205 D', 'OG SER 205 D', 'N SER 206 D', 'CB TYR 210 D', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', 'CE1 TYR 210 D', 'CG TYR 210 D', 'O ILE 228 D', 'CB LEU 232 D', 'CD1 LEU 232 D', 'CA PRO 233 D', 'CB PRO 233 D', 'CG PRO 233 D', 'SD MET 236 D', 'CD2 LEU 269 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'C MET 261 E', 'CA MET 261 E', 'CB MET 261 E', 'CE MET 261 E', 'O MET 261 E', 'CG2 THR 262 E', 'OG1 THR 262 E', 'CB ASN 265 E', 'CG ASN 265 E', 'ND2 ASN 265 E', 'C LEU 285 E', 'CB LEU 285 E', 'O LEU 285 E', 'CA MET 286 E', 'CG MET 286 E', 'N MET 286 E', 'CB PHE 289 E', 'CD1 PHE 289 E', 'CD2 PHE 289 E', 'CE2 PHE 289 E', 'CG PHE 289 E', 'CZ PHE 289 E', '             ', '             ', '             ']
['             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C', '             ', 'OD1 ASN 60 C', 'CE1 PHE 77 C', 'CE2 PHE 77 C', 'CZ PHE 77 C', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D', 'C HIS 102 D', 'CA HIS 102 D', 'CB HIS 102 D', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'O SER 159 D', 'CA TYR 160 D', '             ', '             ', 'O TYR 160 D', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D', 'CA SER 205 D', 'CB SER 205 D', 'OG SER 205 D', 'N SER 206 D', 'CB TYR 210 D', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', '             ', 'CG TYR 210 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ']
['CD2 LEU 118 A', 'CB THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CZ ARG 67 A', 'NE ARG 67 A', 'NH2 ARG 67 A', 'CD GLU 155 B', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B', 'CB PHE 200 B', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', 'CB THR 202 B', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', '             ', '             ', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', '             ', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B', 'CZ TYR 205 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CE1 TYR 97 B', 'CZ TYR 97 B', 'OH TYR 97 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD2 LEU 118 D', 'CB THR 130 D', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD ARG 67 D', 'CZ ARG 67 D', 'NE ARG 67 D', 'NH2 ARG 67 D', 'CD GLU 155 E', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E', '             ', 'CA TYR 157 E', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', '             ', 'O TYR 157 E', '             ', 'CB PHE 200 E', 'CE2 PHE 200 E', 'CB THR 202 E', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', '             ', '             ', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', '             ', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', '             ', 'CZ TYR 205 E', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CE1 TYR 97 E', 'CZ TYR 97 E', 'OH TYR 97 E']
```

Especially

```
 'CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C', 'ND2 ASN 60 C', '           
          ', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C'
, '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '
```

Is there any way to prevent this alignment slip?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to do it with lists? Couldn't you use a dataframe from pandas? Because if visualization is your goal, that would propably be more appropriate.

Comment: Look at your `DataFrame` instead of the printed `list` results.  Are they misaligned? I tried your sample but it seems it's doing what you want already.  Perhaps you're seeing misalignment due to character width? Port the `df` out to an excel and cross check.  You also don't need to sort the lists previously - just sort all the columns in `pandas` after.

Comment: Try filling the `nan`s with space appropriate to the `len` of the `str`.  How does that look? As it stands, it's rather unclear what you want.  The `df` looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost just right, just add a padding to each string to make them align perfectly:

```
l = [
['             ', 'CB THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CB PHE 65 A', 'CZ ARG 67 A', 'NE ARG 67 A', 'NH2 ARG 67 A', '             ', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B', 'CB PHE 200 B', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', '             ', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', 'CB TYR 205 B', 'CD1 TYR 205 B', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', 'CE1 TYR 205 B', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B', 'CZ TYR 205 B', 'OH TYR 205 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CE1 TYR 97 B', '             ', 'OH TYR 97 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CB THR 130 D', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CB PHE 65 D', 'CD1 PHE 65 D', 'CE1 PHE 65 D', '             ', 'CZ ARG 67 D', 'NE ARG 67 D', 'NH2 ARG 67 D', 'CD GLU 155 E', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E', 'C TYR 157 E', 'CA TYR 157 E', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', 'CZ TYR 157 E', 'O TYR 157 E', 'OH TYR 157 E', '             ', '             ', 'CB THR 202 E', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', 'CB TYR 205 E', 'CD1 TYR 205 E', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', 'CE1 TYR 205 E', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', 'CG TYR 205 E', 'CZ TYR 205 E', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'OH TYR 97 E'],
['             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CG2 ILE 228 A', 'O ILE 228 A', 'CB LEU 232 A', 'CD1 LEU 232 A', 'CA PRO 233 A', 'CB PRO 233 A', 'CG PRO 233 A', 'O PRO 233 A', 'SD MET 236 A', 'OG1 THR 237 A', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'C MET 261 B', 'CA MET 261 B', 'CB MET 261 B', 'CE MET 261 B', 'O MET 261 B', 'CG2 THR 262 B', 'OG1 THR 262 B', 'CG ASN 265 B', 'ND2 ASN 265 B', 'C LEU 285 B', 'CB LEU 285 B', 'O LEU 285 B', 'CE MET 286 B', 'CG MET 286 B', 'N MET 286 B', 'SD MET 286 B', 'CB PHE 289 B', 'CD1 PHE 289 B', 'CD2 PHE 289 B', 'CE1 PHE 289 B', 'CE2 PHE 289 B', 'CG PHE 289 B', 'CZ PHE 289 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C', 'ND2 ASN 60 C', '             ', '             ', 'CE2 PHE 77 C', 'CZ PHE 77 C', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D', '             ', 'CA HIS 102 D', 'CB HIS 102 D', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'O SER 159 D', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 160 D', 'CE1 TYR 160 D', 'O TYR 160 D', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D', 'CA SER 205 D', 'CB SER 205 D', 'OG SER 205 D', 'N SER 206 D', 'CB TYR 210 D', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', 'CE1 TYR 210 D', 'CG TYR 210 D', 'O ILE 228 D', 'CB LEU 232 D', 'CD1 LEU 232 D', 'CA PRO 233 D', 'CB PRO 233 D', 'CG PRO 233 D', 'SD MET 236 D', 'CD2 LEU 269 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'C MET 261 E', 'CA MET 261 E', 'CB MET 261 E', 'CE MET 261 E', 'O MET 261 E', 'CG2 THR 262 E', 'OG1 THR 262 E', 'CB ASN 265 E', 'CG ASN 265 E', 'ND2 ASN 265 E', 'C LEU 285 E', 'CB LEU 285 E', 'O LEU 285 E', 'CA MET 286 E', 'CG MET 286 E', 'N MET 286 E', 'CB PHE 289 E', 'CD1 PHE 289 E', 'CD2 PHE 289 E', 'CE2 PHE 289 E', 'CG PHE 289 E', 'CZ PHE 289 E', '             ', '             ', '             '],
['             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C', '             ', 'OD1 ASN 60 C', 'CE1 PHE 77 C', 'CE2 PHE 77 C', 'CZ PHE 77 C', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D', 'C HIS 102 D', 'CA HIS 102 D', 'CB HIS 102 D', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'O SER 159 D', 'CA TYR 160 D', '             ', '             ', 'O TYR 160 D', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D', 'CA SER 205 D', 'CB SER 205 D', 'OG SER 205 D', 'N SER 206 D', 'CB TYR 210 D', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', '             ', 'CG TYR 210 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             '],
['CD2 LEU 118 A', 'CB THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CZ ARG 67 A', 'NE ARG 67 A', 'NH2 ARG 67 A', 'CD GLU 155 B', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B', 'CB PHE 200 B', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', 'CB THR 202 B', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', '             ', '             ', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', '             ', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B', 'CZ TYR 205 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CE1 TYR 97 B', 'CZ TYR 97 B', 'OH TYR 97 B', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD2 LEU 118 D', 'CB THR 130 D', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD ARG 67 D', 'CZ ARG 67 D', 'NE ARG 67 D', 'NH2 ARG 67 D', 'CD GLU 155 E', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E', '             ', 'CA TYR 157 E', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', '             ', 'O TYR 157 E', '             ', 'CB PHE 200 E', 'CE2 PHE 200 E', 'CB THR 202 E', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', '             ', '             ', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', '             ', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', '             ', 'CZ TYR 205 E', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CE1 TYR 97 E', 'CZ TYR 97 E', 'OH TYR 97 E']
]

for i in l:
    print([a.ljust(13) for a in i])
```

Output:

```
['             ', 'CB THR 130 A ', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CB PHE 65 A  ', 'CZ ARG 67 A  ', 'NE ARG 67 A  ', 'NH2 ARG 67 A ', '             ', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B  ', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B  ', 'CB PHE 200 B ', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', '             ', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', 'CB TYR 205 B ', 'CD1 TYR 205 B', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', 'CE1 TYR 205 B', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B ', 'CZ TYR 205 B ', 'OH TYR 205 B ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CE1 TYR 97 B ', '             ', 'OH TYR 97 B  ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CB THR 130 D ', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CB PHE 65 D  ', 'CD1 PHE 65 D ', 'CE1 PHE 65 D ', '             ', 'CZ ARG 67 D  ', 'NE ARG 67 D  ', 'NH2 ARG 67 D ', 'CD GLU 155 E ', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E  ', 'C TYR 157 E  ', 'CA TYR 157 E ', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', 'CZ TYR 157 E ', 'O TYR 157 E  ', 'OH TYR 157 E ', '             ', '             ', 'CB THR 202 E ', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', 'CB TYR 205 E ', 'CD1 TYR 205 E', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', 'CE1 TYR 205 E', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', 'CG TYR 205 E ', 'CZ TYR 205 E ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'OH TYR 97 E  ']
['             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CG2 ILE 228 A', 'O ILE 228 A  ', 'CB LEU 232 A ', 'CD1 LEU 232 A', 'CA PRO 233 A ', 'CB PRO 233 A ', 'CG PRO 233 A ', 'O PRO 233 A  ', 'SD MET 236 A ', 'OG1 THR 237 A', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'C MET 261 B  ', 'CA MET 261 B ', 'CB MET 261 B ', 'CE MET 261 B ', 'O MET 261 B  ', 'CG2 THR 262 B', 'OG1 THR 262 B', 'CG ASN 265 B ', 'ND2 ASN 265 B', 'C LEU 285 B  ', 'CB LEU 285 B ', 'O LEU 285 B  ', 'CE MET 286 B ', 'CG MET 286 B ', 'N MET 286 B  ', 'SD MET 286 B ', 'CB PHE 289 B ', 'CD1 PHE 289 B', 'CD2 PHE 289 B', 'CE1 PHE 289 B', 'CE2 PHE 289 B', 'CG PHE 289 B ', 'CZ PHE 289 B ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 58 C ', 'CD2 TYR 58 C ', 'CE1 TYR 58 C ', 'CE2 TYR 58 C ', 'CG TYR 58 C  ', 'CZ TYR 58 C  ', 'OH TYR 58 C  ', 'ND2 ASN 60 C ', '             ', '             ', 'CE2 PHE 77 C ', 'CZ PHE 77 C  ', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D ', '             ', 'CA HIS 102 D ', 'CB HIS 102 D ', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D ', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D  ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'O SER 159 D  ', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 160 D', 'CE1 TYR 160 D', 'O TYR 160 D  ', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D  ', 'CA SER 205 D ', 'CB SER 205 D ', 'OG SER 205 D ', 'N SER 206 D  ', 'CB TYR 210 D ', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', 'CE1 TYR 210 D', 'CG TYR 210 D ', 'O ILE 228 D  ', 'CB LEU 232 D ', 'CD1 LEU 232 D', 'CA PRO 233 D ', 'CB PRO 233 D ', 'CG PRO 233 D ', 'SD MET 236 D ', 'CD2 LEU 269 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'C MET 261 E  ', 'CA MET 261 E ', 'CB MET 261 E ', 'CE MET 261 E ', 'O MET 261 E  ', 'CG2 THR 262 E', 'OG1 THR 262 E', 'CB ASN 265 E ', 'CG ASN 265 E ', 'ND2 ASN 265 E', 'C LEU 285 E  ', 'CB LEU 285 E ', 'O LEU 285 E  ', 'CA MET 286 E ', 'CG MET 286 E ', 'N MET 286 E  ', 'CB PHE 289 E ', 'CD1 PHE 289 E', 'CD2 PHE 289 E', 'CE2 PHE 289 E', 'CG PHE 289 E ', 'CZ PHE 289 E ', '             ', '             ', '             ']
['             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD1 TYR 58 C ', 'CD2 TYR 58 C ', 'CE1 TYR 58 C ', 'CE2 TYR 58 C ', 'CG TYR 58 C  ', 'CZ TYR 58 C  ', 'OH TYR 58 C  ', '             ', 'OD1 ASN 60 C ', 'CE1 PHE 77 C ', 'CE2 PHE 77 C ', 'CZ PHE 77 C  ', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D ', 'C HIS 102 D  ', 'CA HIS 102 D ', 'CB HIS 102 D ', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D ', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D  ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'O SER 159 D  ', 'CA TYR 160 D ', '             ', '             ', 'O TYR 160 D  ', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D  ', 'CA SER 205 D ', 'CB SER 205 D ', 'OG SER 205 D ', 'N SER 206 D  ', 'CB TYR 210 D ', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', '             ', 'CG TYR 210 D ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ']
['CD2 LEU 118 A', 'CB THR 130 A ', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CZ ARG 67 A  ', 'NE ARG 67 A  ', 'NH2 ARG 67 A ', 'CD GLU 155 B ', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B  ', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B  ', 'CB PHE 200 B ', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', 'CB THR 202 B ', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', '             ', '             ', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', '             ', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B ', 'CZ TYR 205 B ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CE1 TYR 97 B ', 'CZ TYR 97 B  ', 'OH TYR 97 B  ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD2 LEU 118 D', 'CB THR 130 D ', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CD ARG 67 D  ', 'CZ ARG 67 D  ', 'NE ARG 67 D  ', 'NH2 ARG 67 D ', 'CD GLU 155 E ', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E  ', '             ', 'CA TYR 157 E ', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', '             ', 'O TYR 157 E  ', '             ', 'CB PHE 200 E ', 'CE2 PHE 200 E', 'CB THR 202 E ', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', '             ', '             ', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', '             ', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', '             ', 'CZ TYR 205 E ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', '             ', 'CE1 TYR 97 E ', 'CZ TYR 97 E  ', 'OH TYR 97 E  ']
```

Comment: Ah, I actually wanted to keep the spacing in between each element for the lists that didn't align. ie                                                                                                                          ````'CB THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A',
'             ', '             ', '             '
'             ', '             ', '             '
'CB THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A',````                                                            is good since it lets me know that there where no elements in the middle two lists that are common.

Comment: You can do what you have so far, plus the padding in my code.

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming your code works if each element of the lists are the same length.

Comment: you mean the entire program I wrote?

Comment: Sorry what I posted is what I used to get the incorrect result in my code. The rest is just reading data from files.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not elegant but I think produces the output you are wanting?

```
def last(str):
    return str.split()[-1]+str.split()[-2]+str.split()[0]


sorted_six_HUP = ['CB THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', 'CB PHE 65 A', 'CZ ARG 67 A', 'NE ARG 67 A', 'NH2 ARG 67 A', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B', 'CB PHE 200 B', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', 'CB TYR 205 B', 'CD1 TYR 205 B', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', 'CE1 TYR 205 B', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B', 'CZ TYR 205 B', 'OH TYR 205 B', 'CE1 TYR 97 B', 'OH TYR 97 B', 'CB THR 130 D', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', 'CB PHE 65 D', 'CD1 PHE 65 D', 'CE1 PHE 65 D', 'CZ ARG 67 D', 'NE ARG 67 D', 'NH2 ARG 67 D', 'CD GLU 155 E', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E', 'C TYR 157 E', 'CA TYR 157 E', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', 'CZ TYR 157 E', 'O TYR 157 E', 'OH TYR 157 E', 'CB THR 202 E', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', 'CB TYR 205 E', 'CD1 TYR 205 E', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', 'CE1 TYR 205 E', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', 'CG TYR 205 E', 'CZ TYR 205 E', 'OH TYR 97 E']
GABA_sorted_six_HUP = ['CG2 ILE 228 A', 'O ILE 228 A', 'CB LEU 232 A', 'CD1 LEU 232 A', 'CA PRO 233 A', 'CB PRO 233 A', 'CG PRO 233 A', 'O PRO 233 A', 'SD MET 236 A', 'OG1 THR 237 A', 'C MET 261 B', 'CA MET 261 B', 'CB MET 261 B', 'CE MET 261 B', 'O MET 261 B', 'CG2 THR 262 B', 'OG1 THR 262 B', 'CG ASN 265 B', 'ND2 ASN 265 B', 'C LEU 285 B', 'CB LEU 285 B', 'O LEU 285 B', 'CE MET 286 B', 'CG MET 286 B', 'N MET 286 B', 'SD MET 286 B', 'CB PHE 289 B', 'CD1 PHE 289 B', 'CD2 PHE 289 B', 'CE1 PHE 289 B', 'CE2 PHE 289 B', 'CG PHE 289 B', 'CZ PHE 289 B', 'CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C', 'ND2 ASN 60 C', 'CE2 PHE 77 C', 'CZ PHE 77 C', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D', 'CA HIS 102 D', 'CB HIS 102 D', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D', 'O SER 159 D', 'CD1 TYR 160 D', 'CE1 TYR 160 D', 'O TYR 160 D', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D', 'CA SER 205 D', 'CB SER 205 D', 'OG SER 205 D', 'N SER 206 D', 'CB TYR 210 D', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', 'CE1 TYR 210 D', 'CG TYR 210 D', 'O ILE 228 D', 'CB LEU 232 D', 'CD1 LEU 232 D', 'CA PRO 233 D', 'CB PRO 233 D', 'CG PRO 233 D', 'SD MET 236 D', 'CD2 LEU 269 D', 'C MET 261 E', 'CA MET 261 E', 'CB MET 261 E', 'CE MET 261 E', 'O MET 261 E', 'CG2 THR 262 E', 'OG1 THR 262 E', 'CB ASN 265 E', 'CG ASN 265 E', 'ND2 ASN 265 E', 'C LEU 285 E', 'CB LEU 285 E', 'O LEU 285 E', 'CA MET 286 E', 'CG MET 286 E', 'N MET 286 E', 'CB PHE 289 E', 'CD1 PHE 289 E', 'CD2 PHE 289 E', 'CE2 PHE 289 E', 'CG PHE 289 E', 'CZ PHE 289 E']
sorted_six_HUO =['CD1 TYR 58 C', 'CD2 TYR 58 C', 'CE1 TYR 58 C', 'CE2 TYR 58 C', 'CG TYR 58 C', 'CZ TYR 58 C', 'OH TYR 58 C', 'OD1 ASN 60 C', 'CE1 PHE 77 C', 'CE2 PHE 77 C', 'CZ PHE 77 C', 'CE1 PHE 100 D', 'CZ PHE 100 D', 'C HIS 102 D', 'CA HIS 102 D', 'CB HIS 102 D', 'CE1 HIS 102 D', 'CG HIS 102 D', 'ND1 HIS 102 D', 'O HIS 102 D', 'O SER 159 D', 'CA TYR 160 D', 'O TYR 160 D', 'CG1 VAL 203 D', 'O GLN 204 D', 'CA SER 205 D', 'CB SER 205 D', 'OG SER 205 D', 'N SER 206 D', 'CB TYR 210 D', 'CD1 TYR 210 D', 'CD2 TYR 210 D', 'CG TYR 210 D']
GABA_sorted_six_HUO = ['CD2 LEU 118 A', 'CB THR 130 A', 'CG2 THR 130 A', 'OG1 THR 130 A', 'CZ ARG 67 A', 'NE ARG 67 A', 'NH2 ARG 67 A', 'CD GLU 155 B', 'OE2 GLU 155 B', 'O SER 156 B', 'CD1 TYR 157 B', 'CE1 TYR 157 B', 'O TYR 157 B', 'CB PHE 200 B', 'CD2 PHE 200 B', 'CE2 PHE 200 B', 'CB THR 202 B', 'CG2 THR 202 B', 'OG1 THR 202 B', 'CD2 TYR 205 B', 'CE2 TYR 205 B', 'CG TYR 205 B', 'CZ TYR 205 B', 'CE1 TYR 97 B', 'CZ TYR 97 B', 'OH TYR 97 B', 'CD2 LEU 118 D', 'CB THR 130 D', 'CG2 THR 130 D', 'OG1 THR 130 D', 'CD ARG 67 D', 'CZ ARG 67 D', 'NE ARG 67 D', 'NH2 ARG 67 D', 'CD GLU 155 E', 'OE2 GLU 155 E', 'O SER 156 E', 'CA TYR 157 E', 'CD1 TYR 157 E', 'CE1 TYR 157 E', 'O TYR 157 E', 'CB PHE 200 E', 'CE2 PHE 200 E', 'CB THR 202 E', 'CG2 THR 202 E', 'OG1 THR 202 E', 'CD2 TYR 205 E', 'CE2 TYR 205 E', 'CZ TYR 205 E', 'CE1 TYR 97 E', 'CZ TYR 97 E', 'OH TYR 97 E']


list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []
list_4 = []


for item in sorted({*sorted_six_HUP, *GABA_sorted_six_HUP, *sorted_six_HUO, *GABA_sorted_six_HUO}, key=last):
    if item in sorted_six_HUP:
        list_1.append(item)
    else:
        list_1.append(' ' * len(item))

    if item in GABA_sorted_six_HUP:
        list_2.append(item)
    else:
        list_2.append(' ' * len(item))

    if item in sorted_six_HUO:
        list_3.append(item)
    else:
        list_3.append(' ' * len(item))

    if item in GABA_sorted_six_HUO:
        list_4.append(item)
    else:
        list_4.append(' ' * len(item))


print(list_1)
print(list_2)
print(list_3)
print(list_4)
```